# Setting up local virtual machine the same as live server

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, vmware, relative-path

I used to develop locally using XAMPP but am now switching to a VMware virutal machine running Ubuntu for my local development. Everything is set up and running a local version of the site fine apart from one thing... There is a script in css/style.css.php that contains the following line but it needs to be written differently depending on which server it is on.

```
fopen("css/style.inc.css"); // Works on the live server

fopen("../css/style.inc.css"); // Works on the local server

fopen("/css/style.inc.css"); // DOES NOT work on either server
```

The file structures are identical on both the live and local machines.
Possibly related to the problem is that the script is not requested directly, but instead mapped via .htaccess when /css/style.css is requested. The .htaccess file looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ rewrite.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

And the rewrite.php file looks like this...

```
if($_GET["q"] == "css/style.css"){
    include("css/style.css.php");
}
```

How do I begin to diagnose what settings are different on the 2 servers so that I can set them up the same?

Comment: Either move your css folder 1 level forward on your local and use the live setting, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The first path: `fopen("css/style.inc.css"); suggest that your CSS folder is in your root directory, like so:

```
-index.php //or whatever file has this line
-css
    -style.inc.css
```

The second path suggest the following structure

```
-css
    -style.inc.css
-some_web_folder
    -index.php
```

Create the same file structure and everything should be fine.

Comment: I can confirm that the file structures are identical. I have a strong feeling it is related to Apache settings but I do not know where to start checking.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Firstly I stumbled upon this excellent article http://css-tricks.com/php-include-from-root/ which got me thinking about exactly what $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] was set to.  So I wrote a script that simply printed it to the screen and this helped me diagnose that I had set up my local virtual machine with a slash on the end of the address.

```
/var/www/vhosts/example.com    <--- What the live site looked like
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/   <--- What the local site looked like
```

So I edited /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com and removed the slash from DocumentRoot and then rewrote my include code as follows:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
fopen($path.'/css/style.inc.css');
```

Apparently this is better practice for future so I am happy to have learned a new standard.

(Do I get a badge for answering my own question *Pats self on back*)